# SUMIF Function - Macro recorder - Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, macros

The following formula works in Excel but, when recorded and then executed I get an Error message. Could it be that 8 SumIf functions are too many in one cell, when executed through a macro?

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""BV"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""SV SZ DG"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""SV lfd DG"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""SV Beitrag lfd"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""SV Beitrag SZ"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'" & _
    "+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""Auflösungsabgabe"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""UEL Folgemonat SV lfd Beitrag"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])"
```

Comment: "I get an Error message" - What error message do you get?

Comment: Error 1004 - Application defined -or object defined error! I am sorry I thought the title was sufficient!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the title, my fault.

Answer (score 3):

Some of your formula is missing. The last `SUMIF` in the first line of your formula ends as `SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""SV Beitrag SZ"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'"` and the next line begins with `+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""Auflösungsabgabe"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])` meaning a parenthesis isn't closed for one of your `SUMIF` formulas. Try this:

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""BV"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""SV SZ DG"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""SV lfd DG"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""SV Beitrag lfd"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""SV Beitrag SZ"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])" & _
"+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""Auflösungsabgabe"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])+SUMIF('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-13],""UEL Folgemonat SV lfd Beitrag"",'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!C[-11])"
```

Answer (score 1):

**If** you are working with an **old Excel version**, there may be a 255 character limit. For

> all strings that you pass from a Visual Basic procedure to a Microsoft Excel sheet
>
> Microsoft Excel truncates the text

**source:**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/105416

As your string is significantly longer, this would cause a problem.